# Find numbers with same first and last digits

Tags: java, arrays

Sorry if I type something wrong, I am new. I want to create a method that takes an array, and gives back an array with the numbers that have the same first and last digits in the previous array.Example: 12 is equal to 1342.

I have created this for loop to go through the numbers, but I don't know how to compare them.

```
public int[] findDuplicates(int[] a) {
      List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                
                if ((//what do I write here) ) {
                    //and here

                }
                
            }
        }

        return result.stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
            .toArray();
    }
```

Comment: Like the second array would contain numbers such as `11` `193491` and `6`?

Comment: Technically, `6` would have the first digit matching the last digit, it's just that in both cases the first and last digit is index `0`. In all honesty, you might have an easier time working with the string values of the integers, since `String c = "12321"` could be compared via `c.charAt(0) == c.charAt(c.length() - 1)`.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. I wanted to know if there is a way to avoid string and just use an array of integers as an input

Comment: You would need to be able to `/10` and `%10` until you hit a `0`, which seems like more work than simple string comparisons. You're concerned with the lexical representation of the number, moreso than the number itself, so imo it's appropriate to work with the strings.

Comment: (In addition to the above, you'd need a `>0` check, since just checking for 0s would fail on, say, `10001`.)

Comment: I wanted to find pairs. The answers below helped me. Thank you

Comment: Note that for pairs, there are only 10 possible digits, and thus `10*10 == 100` possible types of pairs. So there may be a storage/cpu optimization available to you where instead of doing comparisons, you can simply "feed" the number into the appropriate set based on what it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to parse your numbers into strings and compare them. I did it this way :

```
public int[] findDuplicates(int[] a) {
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean[] numbersThatHaveBeenAdded = new boolean[a.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {

            String iNumber = String.valueOf(a[i]);
            String jNumber = String.valueOf(a[j]);
            if (iNumber.charAt(0) == jNumber.charAt(0)
                && iNumber.charAt(iNumber.length()-1) == jNumber.charAt(jNumber.length()-1)) {

                if (!numbersThatHaveBeenAdded[i]) {
                    result.add(a[i]);
                    numbersThatHaveBeenAdded[i] = true;
                }
                if (!numbersThatHaveBeenAdded[j]) {
                    result.add(a[j]);
                    numbersThatHaveBeenAdded[j] = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return result.stream()
        .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
        .toArray();
}
```

And I used a boolean array to keep in memory the numbers I already added in the result, to avoid duplication.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the while loop (number /= 10) algorithm to get the first digit.
And number % 10 to get the last digit.
And then you can compare between them with if condition, if true you add that number to the list.
And do not forget the return type of that method it must be List

```
public List<Integer> findDuplicates(int[] array){
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        int firstDigit = array[i];
        int lastDigit = array[i] % 10;
        while (firstDigit >= 10)
            firstDigit /= 10;
        if (firstDigit == lastDigit)
            result.add(array[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to compare the number to every other numbers, I added some more code to yours and it works, thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I prefer to do this using integers instead of strings.

You can do it pretty easily with math using a `log` function.  Here, `^` is exponentiation.  This uses the fact that for some number `n`,  `n = 10^y`, where `y = log10(n)`.  Unless `y` is a power of `10`, it will have a fractional part which should be ignored. So `log10(12345) = 4.091491094267951`.  Ignoring the fraction and computing `10^4 == 10,000` which will yield `1` when dividing `12345`.  The right most digit is simply `12345 % 10` using the remainder operator.

```
int[] testData = {1,3,122,121,455,19202,20222, 29927, 291957, 49855, 291293};
int[] result = findDuplicates(testData);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

prints

```
[29927, 291957, 1, 121, 122, 19202, 455, 49855]
```

This method uses a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` to collect the values.

- The key is the first and last digits combined `firstDigit * 10 + lastDigit` which is determined in the `getFirstAndLast` method.
- Once the map is generated, the values are processed to return just the array of values which met the criteria. Since this works with a single iteration, no duplicates will occur *unless* they were included in the data.

```
public static int[] findDuplicates(int[] array) {
    // collect into a map. Key = firstDigit * 10 + lastDigit
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = Arrays.stream(array).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i->getFirstAndLast(i)));
    
    // map.values() returns a `Collection of lists.
    // The following transforms the those Collections to a flattened array 
    // of ints, ignoring lists that have a single, unique, value.
    return map.values().stream().filter(list -> list.size() > 1)
            .flatMap(List::stream).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

- The method takes the target and the digits argument.
- The digits from the target are extracted and compared the supplied digits value by building the digits value from the first and last digits of the target.

```
public static int getFirstAndLast(int target) {
    int divisor = (int) Math.pow(10, (int) Math.log10(target));
    int firstDigit = target / divisor;
    int lastDigit = target % 10;
    return firstDigit * 10 + lastDigit;
}
```

**Notes:**

- `Arrays` are cumbersome, especially when working between primitive arrays and arrays or `Lists` of objects. I recommend you use `Collections` where ever possible.
- The two statements in the `findDuplicates` method could have been combined. However, I find doing so to be cluttered and of no performance benefit.

Comment: @eScapeCS  I added more information which may help.  Please check it out.